# Tracking web-to-device installs using Google Analytics v4

Tags: android, google-analytics

As asked and answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12612108/876603, getting the referrer broadcast and monitoring web to device installs was not possible in GoogleAnalytics v2.

In the [documentation for Google Analytics v4,](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns) no such thing is mentioned, and it even says:

> Google Play Campaign Attribution - See which campaigns, **websites**, and other apps are referring users to Google Play Store to download your app.

But still I can't seem to get a web to device tracking.

Is this still not supported? Is there anything special that needs to be dome for this to work?

Comment: Nope... I could not :\

Comment: I was able to do campaign attribution by following this guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder