# Referral Value is not passing when installing app from Google play site

Tags: android

Hello I'm installing an app from Google play Website from laptop in which I have appended the referral value in it.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.example&referrer=utm_source%3DUNOKNA%26utm_medium%3Dinvite

On click on `Install` button of web site then app downloading starts on user device. Once it has installed then I don't get the referral value whatever it is.

[image]

When I do same in the android device (phone/tablet), once click on link it open the Google Play Android App and pass that value and it works always.

Comment: May be you should first try this sample https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.stevemiller.android.referrertest

Comment: You can also carry this discussion forward https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/fwqK47yJUAE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but not is possible.
You have here another question like yours, seems web-to-app doesn't work

[Install referrer is not tracking on android web market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072467/install-referrer-is-not-tracking-on-android-web-market)

Answer (score 1):

**It's unfortunately not possible.**

I ran into this same tracking problem so I contacted Google Analytic's enterprise support.

I was told this:

> Google Play Referral report only reports data for the Google Play
>   Android app, so conversions that occur in the Google Play website or
>   mobile web site are not included in this report.